# Authenticating netbeans projects to connect with openshift?

Tags: java, netbeans, openshift

I have create a application in open shift. When connecting it to net beans platform in severer area its asking for authentication required form. I have added user name and password of open shift website login and i also added public key and content, but nothing seems to works. What should be add here?

[image]